# Empty variable in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, random

I have this one-liner which works entirely fine.

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters, digits

def pwd_generator(pwd):

    password = "".join([random.choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(pwd)])
    print(password)
```

I wanted to translate that now into a 'normal' for-loop.

```
def pwd_generator(pwd):
    password = ''
    for i in range(pwd):
        password.join([random.choice(ascii_letters + digits)])

    print(password)
```

In this scenario however, `password` is empty.

**Why is the variable empty when I try to write it in a 'proper' for-loop?**

Comment: you're doing 2 different things. `join` returns a value and you're doing nothing with it in the 2nd example.

Comment: you are not _assigning_ the value from join to anything - so it's return is lost ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable so `password.join` returns a string but doesn't save it to password. Instead you should be saving your strings in a list and joining them at the end:

```
password = []
for i in range(pwd):
    password.append(random.choice(ascii_letters + digits)

return "".join(password)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I first tried to append the string, or join it to the list but not to append to a list.